# I need help to Derive F & G

Tags: logic

Derive F & G

1. F=G. Assump.
2. F v G. Assump.

?   G.

F & G. & I 1-?

Should l use disjunction elimination or biconditional elim. next? I am flubbered

Help

Comment: Maybe you should try both and then try to understand the reasons for success and failure? That's how you learn the most.

Comment: I tried disjunction say let’s try disjunction F (assump) | G 2 V elimin. G(assump)|G 2 V eliminate.  Sorry for poor formatting.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because forum is not a logic homework help site.

Comment: I solved it. Plus it is not a homework problem. I am bored and doing it for fun

Comment: Although the problem is probably trivial, I have no idea what you're asking here. Derive G from F & G? And in what kind of deduction system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disjunction Elimination has a "Proof by Cases" structure.

```
m.|  A v B
n.|  |_ A
  |  |  :
o.|  |  C
  |  + 
p.|  |_ B
  |  |  :
q.|  |  C
  |  C            vE m,n-o,p-q
```

Biconditional Elimination .. has various presentations, but basically

```
m.|   A = B
n.|   A
  |   B          =E m,n
```

or perhaps it eliminates to the conditionals so...

```
m.|  A = B
n.|  A
o.|  A > B      =E m
  |  B          >E o,n
```

Check how your particular version operates.

But basically your proof will be a Disjunction Elimination, whose subproof for each case shall contain a Biconditional Elimination *and* Conjunction Introduction.

The later being of the form:

```
  m.|  A
  n.|  B
    |  A & B   &I m,n
```

---

Like so...

```
 1.|  F = G        Premise
 2.|_ F v G        Premise
 3.|  |_ F         Assume
   |  |  :
   |  |  G         via =E however it works
   |  |  F & G     &I 3, ?
   |  +
   |  |_ G         Assume
   |  |  :
   |  |  F & G     Somehow
   |  F & G        vE 2, 3-?, ?-?
```

Just fill in the missing details.

Comment: Where could l get a good version of Fitch